# javascript button toggle only one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use buttons to filter a list of elements in a page.

So far if one of the buttons is clicked all the others will be disabled and then if I click a different one then only that will be enabled and the others will be disabled.

I cannot work out how to toggle it so if the button was already active it would un-disable all buttons including itself.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9eoc6cL/)

html:

```
<div class="calendar-filter">
    <a href="#" class="dnco calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Duty NCO</a>
    <a href="#" class="main calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Main Cadets</a>
    <a href="#" class="wmt calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Wing Marching Team</a>
    <a href="#" class="juniors calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Juniors</a>
    <a href="#" class="exercise calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Exercise</a>
    <a href="#" class="other calendar-color-key btn btn-raised"><i class="material-icons"></i>Other</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
function filterButtonClick(buttonClass) {
    $('.calendar-color-key').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');

        if($(this).hasClass(buttonClass)) {
            $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
}

$('.calendar-color-key').on('click', function() {
    var filterButtonClasses = this.classList;
    filterButtonClick(filterButtonClasses[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".calendar-color-key").click(function() { //select by class
  var clicked = $(this);

  if (clicked.hasClass('toggle')) {
    $('.calendar-color-key').removeClass('disabled'); //enable all again  
    clicked.removeClass('toggle');
  } else {
    $('.calendar-color-key').removeClass('toggle');
    clicked.addClass('toggle');
    clicked.removeClass('disabled');
    $('.calendar-color-key').not(clicked).addClass('disabled'); //disable everything except clicked element
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6kx8ncdb/2/

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work.  I'm trying to toggle the `disabled` class on all elements when that button is clicked and change the active button to another element if that is clicked instead.

Comment: @georgehartlett update (because you talk about `disable`, but it's a `class` called disable). Also added a `color` in `css` to make it more clear

Comment: That's almost there! Once a button is clicked and is 'active' I want to be able to click it again to un-disable all the buttons like a toggle

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect!  Thanks so much

Comment: @georgehartlett look at the bug

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a class default class for your buttons like filter-button so when you want to disable them all just use:

```
$(".filter-button").addClass("disabled");
```

And use an active class it would be a big help so you can have

```
$(".active").on('click', function(){
    $(".filter-button").addClass("disabled");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

UPDATE: don't forget to remove the active class when adding disabled I updated the code.